# Existence of solution for all times

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I wanted to show that Lotka-Voltera competition equations are defined for all $t>0$. Is it suffice to show that solutions are bounded? 
$$\frac{dN_j}{dt}=r_jN_j\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ji} N_i\right)$$
And now : $$\frac{dN_j}{dt}\le r_jN_j$$
$$N_j\le e^{r_j t}$$ so for all finite $t$ it is bounded.

Comment: Indeed, it suffices to show that the solutions are bounded (in case they are). But how do you get the second and third formulas?

Comment: I can show that $N_i$ is bigger than zero for $N_i(0)>0$. Then we can estimate : $\frac{dN_j}{dt}=r_jN_j\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ji} N_i\right)\le r_j N_j$ (It's true because all N_i are bigger than zero)?

Comment: OK then for the second line.

Comment: We may write $\frac{dz_j}{dt}=r_j z_j$ which has solution $z_j= e^{r_j t}$ Now $N_j(0)\le z_j(0)$ and $\frac{dN_j}{dt}\le\frac{dz_j}{dt}$ on some $(0,t)$. So we may conclude that $N_j\le z_j$ on (0,t)?